# Creating and calling a function with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery script that I run multiple times, with multiple events. I would like to save space and turn it into a function to call whenever I need it. How do I do this in JQuery?

My JQuery Script:

```
var $container = $('#timeline-posts-wrap');
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.post-wrap'
    });
});
```

Comment: You're asking how to create a function? That's not specific to the jQuery library. It's a JavaScript language feature. Or are you talking about a jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extract the function:

```
var $container = $('#timeline-posts-wrap');

$container.imagesLoaded(afterImagesLoaded);

function afterImagesLoaded(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.post-wrap'
    });
}
```

It's not "jQuery specific", simply javascript functions.